# delphi TActionMainMenuBar Direction Right To Left

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, alignment, right-to-left

when using TActionMainMenuBar, is there a way to align the Actions component and sub menus from right to left?

changing the bidi didnt apear to change

setting Bidiparent to false didn't help

changing Align to AlRight didnt help

seting at OnShow

```
  Application.BidiMode := bdRightToLeft;
  SysLocale.MiddleEast := true;
```

any more ideas?

Update: changing the actionManager.Style to windows xp did help.

I did customize the code first, however the change was reflected only at Design Time, and only to the "category". The actions themselves stayed left To right.

Comment: Also setting `ActionManager.ActionBars[0].GlyphLayout` or `ActionManager.ActionsBars[0].Items[*].BackgroundLayout` doesn't seem to change the behaviour. Though, I'm not sure what these properties are supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in the `TActionMainMenuBar` component that has been submitted to Quality Central: [QC#10877](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=10877).

The fault was reported way back in 2005 and since it hasn't been fixed yet I don't hold out much hope that it ever will be fixed.

I doubt very much that there is an easy workaround and suspect that you may need to resort to `TMainMenu`. You're only hope would be to include the ActnMenus VCL unit into your own project and then find and fix the bug.  I've done this time and time again for the numerous bugs in `TMainMenu` and `TPopupMenu` but I'm afraid I have no experience with `TActionMainMenuBar` and none with right to left drawing.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the TMainMenu and set the BiDiMode = bdRightToLeft, then everything are on the right site.

Comment: OP expects a sub menu on the left side of a menu item. Also I think he/she expects the glyphs, captions and hotkeys flipped.

Comment: @NGLN `TMainMenu` handles RTL fine. In fact, in certain ways, it actually works better in RTL mode than in LTR mode believe it or not!!